# App rejected because of "Gifting" feature in my iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, app-store

In my app people can send each other virtual gifts which they can use within the app.

- Gifts can be purchased using Coins.
- Coins can be purchased using Consumable in app purchases.
- I am storing everything on my server.

Here is what I got from apple.

> As indicated in the previous correspondence, your app includes "gifting" feature allowing users to send virtual gift using the purchased Consumable coins and the recipient can use the received item.
>
> It would be appropriate to remove gifting feature from your app.

There is nothing in the AppStore Guidelines regarding "gifting" features. Can someone shed some light on this matter ?

How can I get my app approved while keeping the Gifting feature?

Comment: anyway, I get your frustration but I see this as offtopic for SO.. there is an appstores forum in area51

Comment: It seems like we are missing the context as to what the "previous correspondence" they refer to said.

Answer (score 1):

I think, one better solution.

**a)** you  use **`Terms & conditions`**  page in your app and explain all things.

**b)** include two things in `Terms & conditions page

1)include an explicit statement in the contest or virtual gift using  rules that specifies that Apple is not a sponsor nor is involved in any way

2)insure that the contest or virtual prizes are not Apple products; using Apple products as prizes suggests an inappropriate association with Apple.

Comment: thanks I will try again after adding these two in my Terms and Conditions Page.

Comment: I have facing that problem,Solve

Comment: so what you are saying is that you had the same problem and the terms and conditions solved it ?

Comment: yes, i had same problem

Comment: @jAmi add terms and conditions  resolved this problem?

Comment: @Deepesh add terms and conditions resolved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to ask them in **Resolution Center** `why should I not use gifting feature in my application as I am following HIG ?` Then they will elaborate in more details the reason of rejection and then if they tell you valid reason then you will have to make changes in your app otherwise they will accept your app.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Have they ever replied you to a message sent by Resolution Center?

Comment: Yes I have discussed many times with them and get my app accepted by telling them my functionality and it use.

Comment: lucky you. I sent them like dozens of messages through Resolution Center and never got a reply :(.

Comment: Well I have been talking to them over the Resolution Center. Did you mean the App Review Board ?

Comment: yes they reply just fine